Get post information (like its text) from linked API by its url
I'm working on a SAAS website, and we need to get the linkedin text's post from a url provided by a user, i've searched how to do it, and it seems that is just too complicated to do this using linked-in api services, actually they are very limited probably for security reasons.
What i'm currently doing is, user inputs the embed  generated by linkedin, and then on the server, i get the "src" value and make a request to the website and then i get the text.
Now this is kind of uncomfortable for users, the next thing i'll be developing is getting the same text but by the post url provided by a user, i'll just add the "/embed" to the string so i can get the information i need
I'm doing this because it's simple and i don't want to pay crazy money for other apis that'd do this for me. My question would be, does this count as "web-scrapping" ? is this legal ? would i have problems legally if i use this approach, this is not like a bot, or multiple automated requests.
Or is it actually possible to do this using their API ? (i haven't found good info for this so i think the answer is still no)
